# Cannot make connection to Firebird 2.5 Server using Delphi XE2

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-xe2, firebird2.5

I have installed the firebird 2.5 Server, created a database and want to make a connection to it with my Delphi XE2 using the Data Explorer. When I add the database details, username and password, I get the following error if I press the test connection button:

```
Borland.Data.TDBXError: DBX Error:  Driver could not be properly   initialized.  Client library may be missing, not installed properly, of the wrong version, or the driver may be missing from the system path.
```

I do not know if I need to add a .dll file to any specific folder. Please Im lost and need help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to copy the `fbclient.dll` file to some folder in the PATH enviroment variable

for example In 32 bits systems copy the fbclient.dll (32 bit version) to the `C:\Windows\System32` folder

for example In 64 bits systems copy the fbclient.dll (32 bit version) to the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` folder

Note  : If you are using the 64 bits version of Firebird you must use the fbclient.dll file from the `<Firebird install path>\Firebird_2_5\WOW64` folder.